# Filter messages with (no subject) in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is there any workaround or way to filter or search for messages that have no subject line?

I can see there is no way to filter messages when some field is "missing".

Comment: did you try "subject:(no subject)"

Comment: yes, it doesn't give any results

Comment: I have found this suggestion: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=0552efa9128c4162&hl=en but it did not work in my case. Give it a go

Comment: This suggestion doesn't work too. I've found that this subject with '' value is simply ignored/removed from filter.

Comment: they might have patched up that hole then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently there is no way to filter by email that is missing x (subject,labels etc)

You could however suggest it via [link](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=suggest)

**MY REF:** [link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=2f84a8199dec71b6&hl=en)

Answer (score 5):

You can consider writing a Google Script that will extract all emails with blank attachments. The script will be something like this:

```
 var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; 
 var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; 
 if (message.getSubject() == "") {
    Logger.log(message.getID());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this through the Google Script, but it can only process letters from the Inbox folder. And most likely there is a limit of 500 letters.

```
function findNoSubject() {
  var labelName = "nosubject";
  var label = GmailApp.createLabel(labelName);
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    if (message.getSubject() == "") {
      label.addToThread(threads[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

subject:(subject:"") does the trick for me

Comment: That simply returns all messages with the word "subject" in the title, including those that say "no subject", but also those with "test subjects needed".

Answer (score -3):

under Has Words Column write:

```
subject:{}
```